# Reading datetime column from ms access database using vb

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic, vbscript, vba

I want to read date time from ms access database .

the column is of datatype DATETIME and value is : 1/27/12 5:10 PM

```
<html>
<body>
<%



Dim Conn
Dim Rs
Dim sql

Dim sConnection


Dim Today as Date //this gives error - unexpected end of file , i want to display current date and time ??? 


Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set Rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

 filepath= Server.MapPath ("mydb.mdb") 
sConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="  & filepath

Conn.Open(sConnection)



sql="select * from items;"

Set Rs = Conn.Execute(sql)

if Rs.EOF then

    Response.write("No records found")
else 


    do until rs.eof


            ctime =     rs("itemadditiondatetime")

            Response.write("<br/>Time : <input name='dateandtime[]' value=" & ctime & "/>" & ctime )


            rs.movenext

    loop

end if

Rs.Close
Conn.Close

Set Rs = Nothing
Set Conn = Nothing


%>
</body>
</html>
```

In all text boxes only date is displayed ( 1/27/12 ) , time is not being displayed , but when I display without text box then whole datetime is displayed. also how do i get date and time separately in two text boxes.

Also ,  I need to format date as yyyy-mm-dd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is classic ASP/VBScript:

```
'Dim Today as Date 
Dim Today ' without declaring data type
```

You can use the [FormatDateTime](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_formatdatetime.asp) function to get the date and/or time component from your `ctime` value.

```
FormatDateTime(ctime, 3) ' long time
FormatDateTime(ctime, 2) ' short date
```

See the linked page for other `FormatDateTime` options in case you prefer different formats than I suggested.

I overlooked "*need to format date as yyyy-mm-dd*".  Unfortunately, `VBScript doesn't provide VBA's Format(ctime, "yyyy-mm-dd")` feature.  So I think you may have to extract the year, month, and day pieces from `ctime`, and them recombine them in the order you want.

```
Year(ctime) & "-" & Right("0" & Month(ctime), 2) & _
    "-" & Right("0" & Day(ctime), 2)
```

I realized you could simplify your ASP code by asking the db engine to give you the date and time pieces formatted as you wish.  Although VBScript can't use the `Format()` function, the db engine can.

```
SELECT
    Format(itemadditiondatetime, "hh:nn:ss") AS time_string,
    Format(itemadditiondatetime, "yyyy-mm-dd") AS date_string
FROM items;
```

Comment: how to display current date and time

Comment: I am very rusty with ASP.  Is this close to what you want? `FormatDateTime(ctime, 3)`

Comment: how do I get the date separately